# How to align imported mesh to grid?

Tags: snapping

I've imported a mesh to blender and it's not aligned to the world so to speak and I need the symmetry. How do I get rid of that rotation?.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> to toggle quad view mode, showing your model along all major axes.

From there, you can rotate with <kbd>r</kbd> for manual corrections. For finer control, hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> while you rotate.

Edit: An alternative method to ensure a symmetric mesh when you're done:

- <kbd>1</kbd> to view from front
- <kbd>Tab</kbd> to enter edit mode
- <kbd>z</kbd> to display wireframe
- <kbd>b</kbd>+box select the whole left side of your mesh (you may need to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> add an edge loop down the mid-line first)
- <kbd>x</kbd> delete selected vertices
- Add and apply a mirror modifier along the x axis

Not sure how this will differ from what you described in your comment, but it's an option

Comment: Ok, thanks. I need perfect match for later work in zbrush so I ended up using manual adjustments and then mesh>symmetrize

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with [Mesh Align Plus](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Modeling/Mesh_Align_Plus) (my addon). After [installing the addon](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Modeling/Mesh_Align_Plus#Installation), either watch the steps in the GIF or read the text version below:

[image: Align a whole mesh, leaving the object origin intact]

The feature you're looking for is the *Quick Align Planes* operator in the *3D View* > *Tools Panel* (T) > *Mesh Align Plus Tab*, in its own panel.

**1. Pick a destination target (stationary plane that you're aligning to)**

- In edit mode (Tab), shift + right click to select the three verts you want to align your object with (a rotated plane primitive can be used here)
- Hit *Grab Destination*

**2. Pick a source target (plane that will be aligned with the destination)**

- In edit mode (Tab), shift + right click to select the three verts that need to line up with the destination when the alignment is applied. Leave them selected.

**3. Apply the operation**

- Click the checkbox for *Enable Experimental Mesh Operations* (your object cannot have non-uniform scaling applied, so this is to warn you of that).
- Make sure the object you want to move is selected, and (in object mode or edit mode) hit *Apply to: Whole Mesh*