# When I Import Two Models Into Blender I Can Only Edit One at a Time

Tags: import

So I made a few models for a project I'm working on and I decided I wanted to certain parts individually and then import them in as a .obj file. So I did that and then when I tried to go into edit mode I could only edit one of objects. Also I noticed that, when highlighted the objects have different shades of orange. I would really appreciate any help I can get to solve this problem.

Thanks, Nova

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Editing multiple objects

First of all, you *can* only edit one object at a time.  Normally if you want to edit multiple objects at a time you will have to join them with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>.  However there is an addon called [multi-edit](https://github.com/antoni4040/MultiEdit-Addon) which allows you to edit multiple objects simultaneously.

### The *active object*

When you go into edit mode with more than one object Blender will keep all other objects selected, but will only allow you to edit the geometry of the *active object*.  The active object is marked by a slightly lighter orange border than other selected objects.  It is typically the object which you single selected last.  If you do a group select (such as box select with <kbd>B</kbd> or brush select with <kbd>C</kbd>) the active object does not change.

Check out [this post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23554/why-is-one-face-on-my-model-gray-instead-of-orange-in-edit-mode/23555#23555) for more on the active object.