# Can't select everything in edit mode?

Tags: edit-mode, selection-tools

I still can't select everything from my model when I go into edit mode. There is a red line all around one piece of my model when the other is selected. I have one modifier on the top part, if it changes anything. Here's a screengrab if it helps identifying the problem.

[image]
[http://imgur.com/5aQL3kh](https://imgur.com/5aQL3kh)

Thanks.

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36559/when-i-import-two-models-into-blender-i-can-only-edit-one-at-a-time/36560#36560

Comment: This fixes the problem but creates another one at the same time :/

Answer (score 1):

The orange lines say: this is an other object.
Select the upper object in object mode and see if I am right.

Comment: You are correct. If I join them the bone isn't attached to anything anymore though.