# Integrating edge loops in grid fill surface

Tags: modeling, mesh, vertices

How can I "grid fill" this edge loop WITH the three interior edge loops smoothly integrated in the mesh surface? The idea is that the latter afterwards are not visible as edges (i.e. smooth). The interior edge loops have exactly the same number of vertices as the side edge loops, so that shouldn't give any problems.

[image]

Comment: *Grid Fill* would work if you select 2 edgeloops per time (just don't select edges *between* them, as it will create new edgeloop instead of old one), it will be too much for it with all loops at once.

Comment: I'm afraid the interior edge loops will then show up as edges in the mesh surface.

Comment: If you mean that the tool would create new geometry instead of using old one, then afaik [it still will use already created](http://imgur.com/U11k00g). Did you try to see if that suits your needs?

Comment: You show it yourself in your video: there's an edge that is created in the surface. How can we get rid of that edge?

Comment: I misunderstood from your question which edge are you asking about. And I'm still guessing that if you mean [this edge](http://imgur.com/33NDP9s), created *between* boundary loop and one of those exhisted, then you have 2 ways. 1.Before using *Grid Fill* dissolve vertices between edges. 2.After using *Grid Fill* select that loop and `X` > *Dissolve Edges*.

Comment: Zak, in the 16X4 surface you show, it's the edge on the right, the one that will inside the total surface, that poses the problem. One you fill up the surface to the right, that edge will show up sharp, or at least visible.

Comment: You can easily smooth any vertice in the mesh by either 1) `W` > *Smooth* and set options on how much to smooth. 2) Using **Smooth** modifier and assigning to it vertex group. 3) Using sculpting (without any multires), just with *Smooth* or any brush with smoothing effect paint with it on adjacent vertece/s.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, one of way to create faces in that mesh is to use [grid fill](http://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/editing/faces.html#grid-fill). There are other options, such as [bridging](http://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/editing/edges.html#bridge-edge-loops) them.

### Using grid fill

1. Start by selecting two pairs of edge loops and the connecting edges, as shown in the picture below.
   [image: selection for edges]
2. Press <kbd>space</kbd> and search for "grid f" and choose "*Grid Fill*".
   [image: grid fill]

Repeat that for each pair of ledge loops, and you will have a full mesh.

[image: animated gif]

---

### Using the bridge tool

Start by selecting all the loops except for the edges on the top and bottom.
[image: selection]

Now simply press W and choose "*Bridge Edge Loops*". Change the number of cuts to match the number of vertices in between each selected edge loop (in your and my example mesh it is 3). You can find that in the [operator](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/23048/2217) half of the tool shelf.
[image]

Now you just have to fill the top and bottom parts. You can quickly do that with the [F2 addon](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/42017/2217) (that fastest way), or by any combination of bridging, and grid fill.

Here is an animated gif showing how I did it with bridging and the F2 addon.
[image: animated gif]

Here is the final result:
[image]