# How to grid-fill a spiral

Tags: modeling

In my newest project I've made a line spiraling downwards in the shape of a sphere, as seen below:

[image]

You can also see how I started to fill the gaps with faces, this was done by manually picking every edge and adding a face.

So I was wondering: is there any other way to quickly fill all the gaps?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: I think the [F2 addon](https://sites.google.com/site/bartiuscrouch/scripts/f2) (comes with Blender) should do this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is an addon called **F2** (comes bundled with Blender by default) which could speed this up.

To enable the addon go to *File* > *User Preferences* > *Addons* (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>) and search for `F2` and enable it.

[image]

Once enabled, this addon adds two new functions to the <kbd>F</kbd> key, one of which should speed up your workflow considerably (the other is described [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/42017/5705)).  Just create the first face of the spiral, then select the inside edge of the new face and hit <kbd>F</kbd> to create a new face along the spiral.  Then keep pressing <kbd>F</kbd> until you have filled the spiral.

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much! People like you are the reason I love this community. Just curious though, how do you make those .GIFs? Again, thanks for taking your time :)

Comment: @EspenSales See [this meta post](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/963/what-is-the-process-for-creating-gifs-for-questions-and-answers) on GIFs.  (If this answer has suffeciently solved your problem you can mark it as [accepted](http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking the [checkmark under the voting buttons](http://i.stack.imgur.com/yblY8.png).)