# Filling in faces quickly

Tags: modeling, mesh, faces

I was watching a video from hokiroya and noticed he filled faces extremely quickly without actually selecting the vertices. It almost appeared like he was scrolling up with filling faces. I was wondering how to do this myself.
[Video in question](https://youtu.be/9jNv6O3KABc?t=55s) 55-57 at .25 speed.

Comment: I guess he's using the **F2 add-on**. Activate it in *User Preferences*. Anytime you hit **F** with an edge/two vertices selected it fills the holes.

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45430/how-to-grid-fill-a-spiral

Answer (score 2):

To do this you can select the edges or vertexes you want and then press **'F'** while in edit mode.
Which actually fills up the selected entities with a single face.
Be careful with ending up with N-gons though with this technique.

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out this question is due to my lack of experimentation and general knowledge.

I found that pressing F repeatedly will fill all of the edges in a row.