# How can I connect many faces across many vertices?

Tags: modeling, mesh, vertices

I have these vertices across from each and I want to connect many faces instead of just one big face.

[image]

Comment: As there are enough vertices in order to form quads you can use F2 addon included in Blender by default

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45430/how-to-grid-fill-a-spiral

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you select both the edge loops, press <kbd>W</kbd> to bring up the specials menu and then select [`Bridge Edge Loops`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/edge/bridge_edge_loops.html) or press <kbd>E</kbd>.  This will draw faces between the edge loops.  If they are of the same number of verts, the faces will be quads.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You also have the Grid Fill tool, especially for closed shapes, and as long as you have an equal number of vertices on opposite sides. In my example I've given 4 vertices on the top and bottom edges but there could be 2 as well.

- Select the whole shape
- Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>F</kbd> > *Grid Fill*
- Your shape is filled with a grid. You can play with the parameters on the bottom of the *T* panel (on the left) if it doesn't work straightaway.

[image]