# How do I make a sphere out of a spiral?

Tags: modeling

How do I make a globe into a hollow sphere made out of a spiral?
In other words, how do I make a spherical spiral, or a spiral follow a spherical shape?

[image: How do I make the globe into something like the picture?]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42131/modelling-a-spiral-around-a-sphere https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45430/how-to-grid-fill-a-spiral

Answer (score 37, accepted):

> **Hey! No more upvotes here, please, drop them on Gorgious's answer**

One way is to use the *Simple deform* modifier.

1. Start with a UV sphere and remove some vertical stripes
2. Add a *Simple Deform* modifier > *Twist*
3. Choose *Z axis* and adjust the rotation

To add thickness, you can use the *Solidify Modifier*

[image]
[image]

Comment: I went the same way as you.. I wonder if there's a way that doesn't torture the quads  quite so much? (Keeps the latitudes more orthogonal to the longitudes).. I think it might be a bit of a hand-build to do that..

Comment: Bevel taper and mirror a loxodrome curve?

Comment: @RobinBetts https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42131/modelling-a-spiral-around-a-sphere

Comment: @batFINGER little bit of maths to do to get the taper right... :(

Comment: I actually used the bezier curve spherical spiral plus a *Screw* modifier, but you end up with the same distorted quads problem

Answer (score 56):

Okay, modifiers enthusiasts, let's have a good one.

- Add a plane in the center of the world. Go into Edit mode. In the *Mesh* menu, choose *Merge > At Center*.

Now we have a unique vertex on $0,0,0$

- Add a *Displace* modifier. Set its direction to X.
- Add a *Screw* modifier, set axis to X. Set the steps to 8, angle to 0 and the screw to 0.5.
- Right-click on the *Screw* value field, choose *Copy as New Driver*. Right-click in the *Displace* modifier *Strength* field, choose *Paste Driver*. Right-click again there and choose *Edit Driver*, change the driver type to *Scripted Expression* and set it to `- screw_offset`.

Now we have a line with $9$ vertices centered along the X axis.

[image]

- Add a *Screw* modifier. Set *Angle* to $0$, axis to Z and *Steps* to $32$. Set the *Screw* value to $10$.
- Add a *Displace* modifier along the Z direction.
- Right-click on the previous *Screw* modifier value field and choose *Copy as New Driver*, right-click on the last displace strength field and choose *Paste Driver*. Right-click again, choose *Edit Driver*, change driver type to *Scripted Expression*, set `- screw_offset`.

Now we have a band centered along X and Y axis :

[image]

- Add a *Displace* modifier, set the *Direction* to Y, *Strength* to $2$
- Add a *Simple Deform*, set to *Stretch* 0, along Z, with a factor  of $-0.40$

[image]

- Add a *Simple Deform*, set to *Twist*, along Z, with and *Angle* of $360°$
- Add an *Empty* in the origin.
- Add an *Array* modifier, set the count to $6$, uncheck *Relative Offset*, check *Object Offset* and set your empty.
- Right-click the *Array Count*, choose *Copy as New Driver*. Go to your Empty's transforms, right-click the Z rotation and choose *Paste Driver*. Right-click again and choose *Edit Driver*. Set driver type to *Scripted Expression* and type `2*pi/count` so that the angle is in radians.

We have so far some sort of pinecone. Tweak the first *Screw* offset so that there is no overlapping mesh when you add a lot of array count.

[image]

- Add a *Cast* modifier, set it to Sphere (default), set the *Strength* to $1$
- Add a *Subdivision Surface* modifier, set the strength to $2$
- Add a *Solidify* modifier, thickness to $0.1$
- Add a nice shiny material to it.

Final result:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Heroic. You're not a Houdini user, by any chance?

Comment: Haha ! Actually I just installed it a week ago and it is really fun but I have trouble getting used to the interface (ironic from a Blender user I guess)

Comment: Hey, why did you copy the original ima... Wow!

Answer (score 18):

Got to chuck one in ....

- UV Sphere, 32x32
- All selected, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> Edge menu > Unsubdivide, 1 iteration
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> select one edge loop, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Numpad +</kbd> expand, then go to Face mode
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> invert selection, delete ..

[image]

- Object-offset array, target: 90 rotated empty at origin, Count 4
- Solidify, Bevel by angle, Subdiv modifiers.

[image]

Comment: Looking good What I had in mind was   this is 2 spherical curve spirals (8 x 70) and (7 x 80) (to have same vert count) converted to mesh, joined then bridge edge loops... only I have no skill at bridging edge loops and am stuck with 2.7x while 2.8.3 builds   )  Got to this as proof of concept after manually filling one face   http://pasteall.org/pic/140f8b6f194c74d47cfccd96d676fb1e

Comment: Ahh I see..I think the bridge has to be offset : F2 gets close, Grid Fill w/offset gets close.. not really working at poles.. you're right.. this solution... a bit of a  cheat.. can't change no. of turns.

Answer (score 13):

**Script-centric approach**

Thanks to a complete build melt down I'm late to the game.

*After playing around with the not unfamiliar add spiral addon in 2.79 (which I find I can no longer use since going default (commando) on 2.8)  while 2.83 re-built decided it could be easier to simply write a script and in the end wired it up as an addon.*

[image]

Addon [Add Spiral Thingy](https://gist.github.com/batFINGER/a6831a816e008f1ddf0958f0f8ea99bd)

*Download install and enable addon, or paste in text editor and run script.*

[image: Add spiral thingy]

Addon to quickly add tapering width and tapering or constant thickness to what is essentially the spherical curve spiral.

The thickness is `width_angle` above and below the spiral at the equator, and zero at the poles. The taper is calculated using `sin(latitude)`

Using addon operator,  add a 2 turn spriral, then array it 5 times using an empty as object offset.

```
import bpy
from math import radians
from bpy import context

bpy.ops.object.empty_add()
mt = context.object

bpy.ops.mesh.add_spiral_thingy(
    segments=128,
    turns=2,
    growth_angle=radians(12),
    thickness_type='TAPER',
    thickness=0.25)
spiral = context.object

array = spiral.modifiers.new(name="Array", type='ARRAY')
array.use_object_offset = True
array.use_relative_offset = False
array.offset_object = mt
array.count = 5

mt.rotation_euler.z = radians(360 / 5)
```

Comment: batFINGER to the rescue :). This is definitely closest to the original image, and I just love the adjustable tapering.

Answer (score 12):

**Shading: an approach to the 'engraved' material**

Since the answers here cover a lot of bases, I couldn't resist having a go at the gravure.

This supplement is based entirely on @Gorgious' [superb lesson in procedural modeling](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/164578/35559), so no credit here for that, please.

To approach the engraved appearance of the OP's reference, @Gorgious' diagonal wave texture is used as a halftone screen...

[image]

Here, illustrating with the yellow-ochre material of the outside of the spiral

- The bottom branch of the tree takes the negative of the light-response of a diffuse-grey version of the surface, so the shadows are white, and adjusts its contrast.
- The top branch takes the negative of the gradated halftone pattern, so its blacks are white.. (here, that's unnecessary, because the sine-wave is its own negative)
- They are multiplied together, and then, using the color-ramp, inverted back to positive and put through a threshold.
- In the last mix, the black-and-white tone approximation is tinted with a 'spot color'.

[image]

The image is detailed with a Freestyle line restricted by Collection to the spiral, and set to catch material boundaries.

EDIT: Answer to @Gorgious.. get rid of the back of the wire-frame sphere with nodes:

[image]

.. bit of a hack, but will do for this job? We'd like to keep enough of the perimeter for that darkening at the edges? Nicer if it faded...

Comment: Wow, this is almost the same image. Amazing!

Comment: Alright ! Awesome addition ! I was wondering how to do the kind of fade-in of the black lines. The other thing I could not recreate was that the wireframe  of the back faces of the sphere are not visible in the background. Any idea how to do it with nodes ?

Comment: @Gorgious .. see edit... only good for a sphere, though..

Comment: Nice !! Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 11):

Or you could make a procedural shader:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Wow, didn't see this one until today :D

Answer (score 4):

Activate Curve: Extra Objects addon (comes preinstalled)
Then just add Curve>Curve Spirals>Spheric
Adjust the settings

[image]

[image]