# I want to make a spiral in a sphere shape that has endpoints which are close together

Tags: modeling, modifiers, 3d-printing

I am attempting to make a spiral in the shape of a sphere that has endpoints closer together than a default sphere. I followed Gorgious' answer to this thread:
[How do I make a sphere out of a spiral?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/164567/how-do-i-make-a-sphere-out-of-a-spiral)

I like the result of this process, but I cannot figure out how to move the endpoints.

I have tried a simple deform modifier, but it warps the model out of the spherical shape.

I am more than willing to provide any additional information if needed.

Any advice you would give would be greatly appreciated.

Blend file as requested:
[image]

Comment: can you provide your blend. file?

Comment: @Chris I just uploaded the file as requested.

Answer (score 1):

Destructively: apply all modifiers and scale in one of the object's axes.  (Alt c convert to->mesh is a quick way to apply all modifiers.)

Non-destructively 1: Create an empty at the center of your sphere.  Designate this empty as the "object" for your Cast modifier.  Check "Use transform" on the modifier.  Scale this empty in one of its axes.

Non-destructively 2: create a single bone armature, weight your vertex (lol) to the bone, and use an armature modifier.  While armatures are typically thought of as animation tools, they can easily be used as modelling tools to create non-destructive, arbitrary transformations.  (Animation is just modelling over time, after all.)

Destructive (left) vs non-destructive 2 (right):

[image]

In that pic, I've placed the armature modifier above the solidify modifier, which keeps your proportions nicer than the leftmost cube (demoing the destructive option above, although you can be slightly less destructive to achieve the same mesh as on the right.)

Comment: Thank you for your response. That is almost what I want. Instead, though would it be possible to rotate the two ends of the sphere so that they are closer on one edge? 

I tried it with a simple deform modifier set to bend, but it warps the shape. I require a sphere for my application.

Check this blend file to see what I mean.



[<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=sDgkzrlk" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/sDgkzrlk/)

I

Comment: @TheLearningCoder Okay, you might consider editing your question to make your goal more clear.  If I wanted to do that, I might start with what you have and then try to use a mesh deform on the model, targeting a sphere that I could edit.