# How to wrap curves fully around a sphere

Tags: modeling, animation, mesh

I am kinda new to blender but id like to do something similar to the copper sphere in this image: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/185590907947581440/849346399811534938/DUHoyg1.png But id like for the segments to taper off the higher they are(if possible). I tried using the method detailed in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-XYuno3DgAo (create a plane, link it to the mesh using surface deform then apply shrinkwrap to the plane w a sphere), it kinda works but using shrinkwrap it does not go all the way around, and the ends will not connect either[image]

I have no real idea how to proceed so I'm wondering if anyone else has a good way to do this. I would appreciate if someone has a way to do this but you still retain control of the individual strips so you can animate them opening up like flower petals but any answer would be very appreciated.

Comment: Although not exactly the same, the topology in the answers to [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/164567/35559) migh give you some starting points.

Answer (score 7):

You can create a UV sphere (here a 16x16), give it a *Simple Deform* (*Twist* mode, 180° and Z axis) and *Subdivision Surface* modifier. Apply the *Simple Deform* (or don't):

[image]

Select one vertical edge out of 2, scale on X and Y (press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> while scaling), bevel, etc:

[image]

If you need it to be animated, you can use shapekeys. You can also do it less destructively with *Array* modifier etc.

Comment: Building upon the glorious answer that @moonbots gave, when using an Array modifier make sure to use an empty to have control of the shape that you want.