# How can I duplicate a linked vertice from edges?

Tags: modeling

[image: Imgur]

Can someone tell me how to do this? Im a learning to modeling, and i think this can help me sometimes.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking about, but is [this](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/42017/2217) what you are trying to do?

Comment: Probably f2 add on and snap to face. The add on is here https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Modeling/F2