# Bridge/extrude/join vertices in a ring

Tags: edit-mode, vertices, shortcut

I have a ring of vertices, and I would like to connect them with another edge together quickly. [image]
I tried bridging 4 vertices together, but that took too long and made faces. Extruding with 'E' would also take too long.
I couldn't find any way to do it before, but here is an example of what I would like to do: https://youtu.be/ENmN5PVMcQQ?t=1m41s
How do I do this?
I tried the bridge loop method, but it does all of the vertices at once, and it creates triangles, which I do not want either.

Comment: use **[Bridge Edge Loops](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/edges.html?highlight=bridge#bridge-edge-loops)**

Comment: Is that what he uses in that part of the tutorial? I get an error saying to select at least 4 vertices to bridge them, and it creates a face as well, where I don't want faces.

Comment: I tried that, but it creates triangles.

Comment: If Bridge creates triangles then there isn't the same number of vertices in those 2 rings of edges. There isn't any other quick solution like Bridge if you want to connect 2 edge loops with different vertex count without any triangles

Comment: Can you figure out what he is using int he video? I've tried everything I could think of. Is there an addon that does this?

Comment: I have no idea what exactly are you talking about. If there is a face connecting 2 edge loops you can use Pick Shortest Path with Ctrl+Right Click on vertices to select all the vertices between one selected first and selected last. Other than that specify concretely which moment of video is unclear

Comment: Immediately in the video, he begins to extrude one by one the vertices that automatically connect to the top one.

Comment: In the tutorial he is using the [F2 addon](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/42017/2217).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this **automatically**, you can use *Bridge Edge Loops* by selecting the rings, pressing <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> and typing "*Bridge Edge Loops*":

[image]

If you prefer a **semi-automatic** way, make sure you have *F2 addon* enabled in *User Preferences* <kbd>Ctr</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> > *Addons*.
Then select 2 vertices using <kbd>F</kbd> and continue filling the loop by moving your cursor in the direction you want to create faces and pressing the <kbd>F</kbd> (can be pressed repeatedly):

[image]