# Creating a face on 2 circles of edge while letting the inside of the small circle without face

Tags: faces

[image: shape without faces]Hello,
I managed to clean all the vertices of the primitives that I join together, removing the faces that where overlapping and keeping a simple shape. 
Now is my problem : I need to create the front and back faces. But when I select all the vertices, and make 'F' to create a face, the 2 holes inside the shape are covered. 
How do I need to proceed to make the face without covering those holes, letting them empty? (the holes are the small circle in the middle and the moon croissant under it)

Comment: Rather than extruding edges, could fill and extrude region. Somewhat related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/146083/create-circle-with-inner-radius

Answer (score 0):

The only method I found is to remove the central cylinder, make the faces, create a cylinder and add a boulean to remove the center in the end. It is dirty :/

Comment: Avoid booleans. use bridge edge loops. https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/92755/97988